# Connect to SQL Server CE database with password

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

How can I connect to the `.sdf` database with a password and still be able to use the tableadapter to FILL out my listbox with this code:

```
try
{
   tbl_sClipManagerTableAdapter1.Fill(db_sClipManagerDataSet1.tbl_sClipManager);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
}
```

Produces this error:

> The specified password does not match the database password. [ Data Source = PATH TO .SDF FILE ]

I have password protected the database. How can I connect with password and still through the tableadapter?

EDIT:

Oh, I don't want to store the password with the connection string - cause it is to easy readable through the config file.

SOLUTION:

I found the solution by myself.

In `DataSet.Designer.cs` find something like:

```
    private void InitConnection() {
        this._connection = new global::System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection();
        this._connection.ConnectionString = global::sClipManager.Properties.Settings.Default.db_sClipManagerConnectionString + "; password=PASSWORDHERE";
```

I just added the `+ "; password=PASSWORDHERE"`.

Everything works now. And the password can't be easily read in the config file.

Best regards

Comment: If you found a solution yourself, add it as an answer to the question and, after a day or so, mark it as the accepted answer. That way the question will be marked as answered, people searching SO will find your answer, and you will get rep if people upvote your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm hoping that query is being executed by some kind of soap/rest service.  If so, you can have that service run with domain credentials.  Then you could give that domain-login access to the db.  Then you could use integrated security in the connection string.  That way the connection string has -zero- credential info.

Comment: Ehm what?
Please see my solution in my question post. I have no idea what your answer is about.

Comment: You want to avoid putting passwords in places where it is easy to see them.  Putting passwords in strings in clear text is unsafe.  So, if you use integrated security, you can avoid having the password in the connection string.

Comment: The question is about an sdf file, not an mdf file. There is no implication that this is being used in a domain context, it could well be a stand-alone application on a mobile device.